# ReactJS Context: Passing array through context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-context

I currently have a project and I need to pass the array to another component for my search bar. I am using React's Context.

I've tried passing my data but I seem to get an undefined value in my console.

Code in **Context.js**

```
Export const SearchContext = createContext();
```

This is the code in **MainPage.js**:

```
const data = [json_1, json_2];

const array = data.map(values => {
 const search = _.flattenDeep(values);
 values.search = search;
 return values;
})

<SearchContext.Provider value={array} />
```

and in my **Searchbar.js**

```
const options = useContext(SearchContext);

console.log(options);

<AutoComplete
                                className="searchbar"
                                placeholder="Search..."
                                dataSource = {options}
                                onfilterOption={(inputValue, option) =>
                                    option.props.children.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1
                                  }
                        />
```

In the console.log I get an undefined value. This data should also be able to populate my search bar.

Comment: `<SearchContext.Provider value={array} />` if this is the exact line you have then you aren't wrapping your consumer inside the context it is going to consume

Comment: So should I put the array inside the context provider instead of putting it inside the value?

Comment: Make sure your SearchBar is a child of SearchContext.Provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at this Gist : https://gist.github.com/nimahkh/9c008aaf2fd2d1cc83cd98c61e54979a

you have to wrap your component with Provider and inside of that component that is Wrapped , you have access to value , it's impossible to fetch value , out of the box